# searching in virtual table (FTS3) in sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, full-text-search, database-indexes, fts3

i create a virtual table for seaching text in database .

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE testtable USING FTS3 (
id INTEGER, -- this field have duplicate values
test1 INTEGER,
test2 INTEGER,
test3 TEXT
)
```

this is word but when i want to search special id get very slow .
also i can't indexing "id" field and get a error :

```
virtual tables may not be indexed
```

want to search like this :

```
select * from testtable where id = 48880
```

how to make fastest search for this query, i search fast without FTS .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On FTS tables, only FTS queries are fast.

The values in the `id` column are indexed as words, so you have to search for them as words:

```
SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE id MATCH '48880'
```